# getdate() on linked server gives me an error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, getdate

I have the following TSQl statement which retrieve Sales orders from sage using Linked server but i dont understand why this line `JrnlHdr.TransactionDate = cast(GETDATE())` gives me any error. I can retrieve all records with out `JrnlHdr.TransactionDate = cast(GETDATE())` but i want to see only sales orders created today.

here is the select statement

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([SAGE],'SELECT DISTINCT Customers.CustomerID, Customers.Customer_Bill_Name, Customers.WhichShipVia, 
LineItem.ItemID as I, JrnlHdr.INV_POSOOrderNumber, JrnlHdr.CustomerInvoiceNo, 
JrnlHdr.Comment2, JrnlHdr.ShipByDate, JrnlHdr.GoodThruDate, JrnlHdr.CustomerSONo, JrnlHdr.Reference, JrnlHdr.TransactionDate,
JrnlRow.DistNumber, CAST (JrnlRow.Quantity AS NUMERIC (20,4)), LineItem.ItemID, LineItem.SalesDescription, LineItem.PartNumber, LineItem.Category, LineItem.ItemClass, LineItem.ItemDescription 
FROM   Customers
INNER JOIN JrnlHdr
ON Customers.CustomerRecordNumber = JrnlHdr.CustVendId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Address
ON Customers.CustomerRecordNumber = Address.CustomerRecordNumber
INNER JOIN JrnlRow
ON JrnlHdr.PostOrder = JrnlRow.PostOrder
INNER JOIN LineItem 
ON JrnlRow.ItemRecordNumber = LineItem.ItemRecordNumber
WHERE  JrnlHdr.JrnlKey_Journal = 11 AND JrnlHdr.TransactionDate = cast(GETDATE()) AND JrnlHdr.PostOrder = JrnlRow.PostOrder  AND JrnlHdr.CustVendId = Customers.CustomerRecordNumber AND JrnlRow.ItemRecordNumber = LineItem.ItemRecordNumber AND JrnlHdr.POSOisClosed = 0')
```

here is the error message i get

> OLE DB provider "PervasiveOLEDB.11.0" for linked server "SAGE"
>   returned message "One or more errors occurred during processing of
>   command.". OLE DB provider "PervasiveOLEDB.11.0" for linked server
>   "SAGE" returned message "[Pervasive][ODBC Engine Interface]Syntax
>   Error: N JrnlHdr.PostOrder = JrnlRow.PostOrder INNER JOIN LineItem  ON
>   JrnlRow.ItemRecordNumber = LineItem.ItemRecordNumber WHERE 
>   JrnlHdr.JrnlKey_Journal = 11 AND JrnlHdr.TransactionDate =
>   cast(GETDATE()<< ??? ". Msg 7321, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 An error
>   occurred while preparing the query "SELECT DISTINCT
>   Customers.CustomerID, Customers.Customer_Bill_Name,
>   Customers.WhichShipVia,  LineItem.ItemID as I,
>   JrnlHdr.INV_POSOOrderNumber, JrnlHdr.CustomerInvoiceNo, 
>   JrnlHdr.Comment2, JrnlHdr.ShipByDate, JrnlHdr.GoodThruDate,
>   JrnlHdr.CustomerSONo, JrnlHdr.Reference, JrnlHdr.TransactionDate,
>   JrnlRow.DistNumber, CAST (JrnlRow.Quantity AS NUMERIC (20,4)),
>   LineItem.ItemID, LineItem.SalesDescription, LineItem.PartNumber,
>   LineItem.Category, LineItem.ItemClass, LineItem.ItemDescription  FROM 
>   Customers INNER JOIN JrnlHdr ON Customers.CustomerRecordNumber =
>   JrnlHdr.CustVendId LEFT OUTER JOIN Address ON
>   Customers.CustomerRecordNumber = Address.CustomerRecordNumber INNER
>   JOIN JrnlRow ON JrnlHdr.PostOrder = JrnlRow.PostOrder INNER JOIN
>   LineItem  ON JrnlRow.ItemRecordNumber = LineItem.ItemRecordNumber
>   WHERE  JrnlHdr.JrnlKey_Journal = 11 AND JrnlHdr.TransactionDate =
>   cast(GETDATE()) AND JrnlHdr.PostOrder = JrnlRow.PostOrder  AND
>   JrnlHdr.CustVendId = Customers.CustomerRecordNumber AND
>   JrnlRow.ItemRecordNumber = LineItem.ItemRecordNumber AND
>   JrnlHdr.POSOisClosed = 0" for execution against OLE DB provider
>   "PervasiveOLEDB.11.0" for linked server "SAGE".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are apparent executing the query on the remote Pervasive database, you need to use syntax for that DBMS, which is `CURDATE()` instead of `GETDATE()`.

Comment: Nice spot on the Pervasive DB / PSQL :-) Invalidates my answer!

Answer (score 0):

can you try this?

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([SAGE],'SELECT DISTINCT Customers.CustomerID, Customers.Customer_Bill_Name, Customers.WhichShipVia, 
LineItem.ItemID as I, JrnlHdr.INV_POSOOrderNumber, JrnlHdr.CustomerInvoiceNo, 
JrnlHdr.Comment2, JrnlHdr.ShipByDate, JrnlHdr.GoodThruDate, JrnlHdr.CustomerSONo, JrnlHdr.Reference, JrnlHdr.TransactionDate,
JrnlRow.DistNumber, CAST (JrnlRow.Quantity AS NUMERIC (20,4)), LineItem.ItemID, LineItem.SalesDescription, LineItem.PartNumber, LineItem.Category, LineItem.ItemClass, LineItem.ItemDescription 
FROM   Customers
INNER JOIN JrnlHdr
ON Customers.CustomerRecordNumber = JrnlHdr.CustVendId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Address
ON Customers.CustomerRecordNumber = Address.CustomerRecordNumber
INNER JOIN JrnlRow
ON JrnlHdr.PostOrder = JrnlRow.PostOrder
INNER JOIN LineItem 
ON JrnlRow.ItemRecordNumber = LineItem.ItemRecordNumber
WHERE  JrnlHdr.JrnlKey_Journal = 11 AND JrnlHdr.TransactionDate = cast(CURDATE()) AND JrnlHdr.PostOrder = JrnlRow.PostOrder  AND JrnlHdr.CustVendId = Customers.CustomerRecordNumber AND JrnlRow.ItemRecordNumber = LineItem.ItemRecordNumber AND JrnlHdr.POSOisClosed = 0')
```

Comment: thanks Raghu i get error `OLE DB provider "PervasiveOLEDB.11.0" for linked server "SAGE" returned message "One or more errors occurred during processing of command.".
OLE DB provider "PervasiveOLEDB.11.0" for linked server "SAGE" returned message "[Pervasive][ODBC Engine Interface]Syntax Error: N JrnlHdr.PostOrder = JrnlRow.PostOrder
INNER JOIN LineItem 
ON JrnlRow.ItemRecordNumber = LineItem.ItemRecordNumber
WHERE  JrnlHdr.JrnlKey_Journal = 11 AND JrnlHdr.TransactionDate = cast(CURDATE()<< ??? ".`